# Apply function when other cell is modified so a referencing cell does not update

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a spreadsheet to manage a business; in particular, I want to use it to register the sales of the day. The problem I'm having is that I need it to copy the price of the product sold from the prices sheet, to the sales sheet, but I need that value to remain the same even if I later modify the price.

I have managed to copy the value of the corresponding product, but whenever I update the price, the old sales change too. To put it simply, I need a script that whenever a cell from column `Product` in the sheet `Sales` is modified, applies a formula that searches in column "Products" (from sheet `Products`, within the same spreadsheet) for the corresponding product name, and then copies the value column "prices" from the sheet `Products`, to `Sales`. So when I need to change the prices, my old sales retain their original value.

Comment: We need something to work with.  Always provide code, error messages, and what line of code is not working.  Use `Logger.log()` statements to print information to the LOGS.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible without a script:

Before updating prices convert the results of formulae that have looked up prices into values (Copy, Paste special).

Comment: yes I know, but i want it to happen automtically to avoid mistakes